# Docker uninstall Sawtooth marketplace

Tags: linux, docker, hyperledger-sawtooth

I just installed Hyperledger sawtooth marketplace from the [Git repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-marketplace) via Docker on my local machine. But, now I want to uninstall all the files but I don't know how to do this.

I ran the `$ docker-compose up` command in the folder `~/Workspace/sawtooth-marketplace` but this folder is just 2.5 mb of file size. And in my opinion it installed a lot more files om my local machine.

Is there a way to reverse / uninstall this piece of software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robbert

To clean out all containers (if you did not do a docker-compose down)

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

To clean out all marketplace images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference="market*" -aq) -f && \
docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference="sawtooth* -aq) -f && \
docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference="validator" -aq) -f
```

Shortcut to remove all docker images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -aq) -f
```

Comment: I get the following response: Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container 0a362c7195f46a7e1987c3a6dd4859455330a4fb0b06e8a06f6e7b0b2e55309f. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove

Comment: Correct, you have to do a `docker-compose -f <compose.yaml> down` first

Comment: Thanks, that was it!